# Spyder pandas.read_html issue

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

In a Python script I'm trying to run this code:

```py
tables = pd.read_html("https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickview.do?SERIES_KEY=120.EXR.D.CHF.EUR.SP00.A")
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
  File ~\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:641 in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

The funny thing is that this **web page is working** and if I execute the same code the **standard Python environment** (downloaded from python.org) I get no error and **the code works as expected**.

How can I fix this? I would like to use Anaconda as my development environment.

Comment: The site is probably responding differently to different "users", i.e user agent etc. You'll run into this when scraping web pages.

Comment: I understand, but why are they accepting connections out of Anaconda? Is Anaconda using a different user agent?

Comment: The website doesn't even work for me in Firefox. It has a big error "Your access has been blocked due to security concerns." :) So it seems to be picky about who to accept.

Comment: I would look for a different data source, what can you do if the site is trying to stop you from scraping it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me in PyCharm:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/quickview.do?SERIES_KEY=120.EXR.D.CHF.EUR.SP00.A'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.read_html(r.content, thousands=None, decimal=',')
```

Don't ask too often. They can get banned. Currency quotes can be taken elsewhere. And the fundamental data is updated not so often, not more than once a month.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick for me! I was searching for their REST API, but this will do for a few days

Comment: If quotes are needed, it is better to use pandas pandas-datareader.